# Display Point Labels in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling

[image: Question]

I have coordinates and points from that coordinates. So what do I need to do to show point numbers on the map?

It's my second day with QGIS

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Making the ids:

1. Right-click on your point layer and `Open the attributes table` from the pop-up menu.
2. Make the layer editable by clicking on the yellow pencil icon
3. Click the `Open Field Calculator` button (last on the right - abacus icon)
4. Ensure that `Create a new field` is checked (it should be by default).  Call the field 'Id' (or something) - you can accept the defaults of Integer, width 10.
5. In the `Functions List` section, expand `Record` (little plus sign next to it) and double click on `$rownum`.  This will add $rownum to the Expressions section.
6. Click OK and then save.

You now have id's based on the row number - you can follow a similar procedure to make Ids based on something else or manually edit them etc.

Next you need to label the points.  Right-click on the points layer and select `Properties` (or double-click on the layer).  Go to the labels section and in the drop-down menu at the top, select Id.  Explore the labeling options to see how to adjust the font, placement etc.  You could also skip the step of making ids and just label using $rownum - I just like explicit ids.

Comment: And how to keep a scale fakctor in composer?

Answer (score 4):

Double click in the points layer, go to label tab, Active "label this layer with" and select the field name: X or Y
If you want both, you can write an expression like X||' - '||Y

Comment: You might also want to use `round(decimal,places)` for prettier labels, e.g. `round(X,2)||' - '||round(Y,2)`

Comment: @SAnderka There is also `Formatting > Formatted Numbers > Decimal places` in the labels tab.